# Is it requirement to implement networkSpeedTestInProgress error for Google Assistant Action traits NetworkControl?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home, google-assistant

In the documentation for NetworkControl command [action.devices.commands.TestNetworkSpeed](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/networkcontrol#action.devices.commands.testnetworkspeed) we can return an error `networkSpeedTestInProgress`.

Are we required to return this error to pass the certification?

Examples:

#1 Without Implementing `networkSpeedTestInProgress`

User asks multiple times `What is my net speed?`. For each request we start a separate speed test one after another.

#2 With Implementation
User asks multiple times `What is my net speed?`. For each request after the first (until it finishes) we respond with `networkSpeedTestInProgress`.

Can we go with option 1?

Answer (score 0):

While both implementations look similar, it is **not** recommended to go with option 1 as you won’t be able to pass the certification.
The ***networkSpeedTestInProgress*** error implementation should be there because since the network speed tests take time, a response mechanism to this trait can't be synchronous.

And due to this reason, we always seek asynchronous responses for this trait, and ask our partner to just respond to executions with networkSpeedTestInProgress. After the partner response, a follow-up response is sent using the correct payload format.

See more at (https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/networkcontrol#follow-up-responses).